# Why does SQL Server Management Studio generate code using square brackets?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When generating code/scripts,

1. why does SQL Server Management Studio generate code using square brackets and not double-quotes?

   SELECT [NAME] FROM [TABLE]
2. and is there a way (setting/registry entry) to configure it to use double-quotes (the standard) instead?

   SELECT "NAME" FROM "TABLE"

*This is very MSFT-ty feature, given that all their documentation now indicate the double-quotes (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx))*

Comment: You say "double-quotes [are] (the standard)". Is that an ANSI standard?

Comment: yes, it is ANSI standard

Comment: "Using brackets, [ and ], to delimit identifiers is not affected by the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting." I think the Sybase legacy and it's behaviors are why this became necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does sql-server (management studio) generate code using square brackets?
>
> SELECT [NAME] FROM [TABLE]

To cope with the names that are reserved words or contain whitespaces.

Square brackets are the native way to wrap the identifiers to. They are asymmetrical and can be unmatched, while the quotes are symmetrical and should be matched (or doubled to include them into the name):

```
CREATE TABLE [[test] (id INT)
CREATE TABLE ["test] (id INT)
DROP TABLE "[test"
DROP TABLE """test"
```

Comment: good point, I know that. I should change wording of my question: i meant why square bracket and not double quotes. will fix.

Comment: Although it covers only half of my question, I will accept the answer as the assymmetrical is a very good argument indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Your link explains why, at least to me. The brackets are not setting-dependant, but the validity of " depends on the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the other half of your question, there is a workaround in SQL Server Management Studio with the Replace All command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

- Find what: `[\[\]]`
- Replace with: `"`
- Check "Use:" and select "Regular expressions"
- Press "Replace All"

Have in mind that this will also replace occurrences of brackets in your comment.